# How to download and add dependent msi using wix?

Tags: wix

Say, project X.msi partially depends on Y.msi i.e X.msi could work independently but some additional features can be enabled using Y.msi And say Y.msi is available online, now on installing X.msi, if user choose to opt Y.msi, the installer should download and automatically install it. Is there a way to achieve this using wix?

Comment: Look at wix bootstrapper: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

Comment: I tried all of them, but as per http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/remotepayload.html and http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Remote-MSI-Payload-td7579500.html  msi can't be remote payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, Windows Installer installs MSIs independently and serially. So, one cannot be a part of another.

You are looking for [MsiPackage/@DownloadUrl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html). The problem is how to design bundle(s) for the desired effect of letting the use choose whether to install Y.msi.

One way is to have two bundles: X.exe and XY.exe

Another way is to create a custom Bootstrapper Application (BA) for your bundle in order to 1) Ask the question and 2) Remove or skip Y.msi if the answer is No.

Things to consider: How to handle the user and/or you changing their mind/evolving? Installed X but now want XY. Installed XY but now want only X. Installed Y and then X but don't know the relationship. New version of Y.msi is published.

Would it be simpler to always install Y.msi with X.msi and allow the user to configure the application to use the Y functionality or not?